# Not getting list of tables from database

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, oracle12c

I am trying to get list of tables owned by current Oracle user.I have created user in oracle in which I am having below 2 tables :

- Categories
- Address

Now when I run below query in oracle then I am getting only above 2 tables which I want :

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```

Reference of above query : https://www.arungudelli.com/tutorial/oracle/list-all-tables-in-oracle-query/

But problem is when i am trying to get list of tables using [GetSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/schema-restrictions) method then i am not getting anything :

```
public Datatable GetTables(DbConnection conn)
        {
              conn.Open();
              if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
              {
                    var tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { "user_tables" });
              }
              conn.Close();
        }
```

[image]

Now when I do like below then I am getting unnecessary tables(> 1000) which are system tables and other tables(dont know from where they are coming though I only have Categories and Address tables) :

```
var tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
```

So I only want to get list of tables owned by current Oracle user.Below is my connection string :

```
data source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyService)))";user id=C##Db1;password=root123;
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: does your user own the tables?

Comment: @LachlanLindsay Yes as I have mentioned in the question that Categories and Adress table are the only tables onwed by user mentioned in the connection string

Comment: When you access the database through c# code, who is the "current" user? It seems that the application connects to the DB as user SYSDBA, or some other admin account (which is why you get thousands of tables). How is the Oracle database supposed to know you want the tables for some specific user, if the application connects as SYSDBA?

Comment: @mathguy Through connection string?because connection string have the information about the user.isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Microsoft's documentation regarding `GetSchema(String, String[])`

> If the "Tables" collection has three restrictions--database, owner, and table name--and you want to get back only the tables associated with the owner "Carl", you need to pass in the following values: null, "Carl". If a restriction value is not passed in, the default values are used for that restriction. This is the same mapping as passing in null, which is different from passing in an empty string for the parameter value. In that case, the empty string ("") is considered to be the value for the specified parameter.

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: So it is not possible what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, you can: String[] tableRestrictions = new String[4];  

         // For the array, 0-member represents Catalog; 1-member represents Schema;   
         // 2-member represents Table Name; 3-member represents Table Type. And in your case it should be new string[] { null, "your_youser", "user_tables" }

Comment: What is your_youser is?because I do not have connection string fixed.I am reading connection string from database

Comment: I am getting error with what you suggested : The Schema 'Tables' does not support more than '2' restrictions

Comment: Sorry for the typo. The your_user should be the owner of the tables. As for the error you are receiving I would suggest to use only 2 restrictions, new string[] { "Owner_of_table", "user_tables" } and see where it gets you.

Comment: Owner_of_table is C##Db1(userid) ??

Comment: When i try like this : conn.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] { "C##Db1", "user_tables" }); This is giving blank datatable